# Cannot await 'long' when calling an async method inside asp.net mvc5

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, entity-framework-6

I have the following async method inside my asp.net mvc 5 web application with EF6:-

```
public async Task<Resource> GetResourceByName(string resourcename)
        {
            return await entities.Resources.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.RESOURCENAME.ToLower() == resourcename.ToLower());

        }
```

now i am trying to get the ID for the returned object from the above method as follow:-

```
 var temp = await GetResourceByName(FQDN).Result.RESOURCEID;
```

but this will raise the following error:-

> Error 1   Cannot await 'long'

now to fix this i did the following :-

```
var temp = await GetResourceByName(FQDN);


id = temp.RESOURCEID;
```

so not sure why my first apporach did not work. now i await the Task, and when it finises i will retrieve the .Result and get the ResourceID ... so why this will not work ?

here is the model for the Resource:-

```
 public partial class Resource
    {
        public long RESOURCEID { get; set; }
        public string RESOURCENAME { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> ACQUISITIONDATE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> WARRANTYEXPIRY { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> EXPIRYDATE { get; set; }
        public long COMPONENTID { get; set; }
        public string ASSETTAG { get; set; }
        public string SERIALNO { get; set; }
        public string BARCODE { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> PURCHASELOTID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> VENDORID { get; set; }
        public long RESOURCESTATEID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> SITEID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<long> CIID { get; set; }
        public bool ISDEPRECIATIONCONFIGURED { get; set; }
        public bool ISDEPRECIATIONCALCULATED { get; set; }
        public bool ISPERSONAL { get; set; }

        public virtual ComponentDefinition ComponentDefinition { get; set; }
        public virtual ResourceLocation ResourceLocation { get; set; }
        public virtual ResourceState ResourceState { get; set; }
        public virtual SiteDefinition SiteDefinition { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awaiting the task will give you the result. If you then want to descend into a property of the result, you'll need to use parenthesis if you want it all in one expression:

```
var temp = (await GetResourceByName(FQDN)).RESOURCEID;
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,, but is writing the following correct " it360id = GetResourceByName(FQDN).Result.RESOURCEID" ??? or it is better to write "var temp = (await GetResourceByName(FQDN)).RESOURCEID;" as u mentioned ?

Comment: @johnG: No, you should not use `Result`. Use `await` instead.

Comment: but why i should use await instead of Result ? second question is my way of storing the call inside a temp variable a good approach :- "var temp = await GetResourceByName(FQDN);


id = temp.RESOURCEID;"

Comment: @johnG: I describe on my blog [one reason not to block on async code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). A more fundamental reason is that on ASP.NET, whenever you block, you're giving up all the advantages of asynchronous code in the first place. Regarding the temp variable, sure, that's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `.Result` on a task blocks the thread until the operation completes.  The result object is of the type specified in `TResult` for the Task.

Your call did not work, because you can't await the Result of the task, only the task itself.  Once you call `.Result` there is nothing to await.

Comment: so you mean this should be correct " it360id = GetResourceByName(FQDN).Result.RESOURCEID;" ?? and using .Result will await for the call ?

Comment: Calling `.Result` is risky, as if you use it incorrectly you can cause deadlocks.  You can read more about that on Stephen Cleary's [blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: so how i should write this instead ? so you mean using await is not risky , while using .Result might cause deadlocks ?

Comment: Exactly how you implemented it with the `temp` variable is fine.

Comment: but i did not understand why using .Result can cause deadlocks while using await will not cause deadlocks,, although they are both the same as i understand them .. they block the execution till the method complete ..is this correct?

Comment: `await` does not block execution.  Read the link I posted plus the [intro post](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html). There is not enough room in the comments to explain async/await fully.

Comment: so you mean await will not really wait for the method to complete or i did not get ur point correctly ? so if i write the following "return await entities.Resources.SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.RESOURCENAME.ToLower() == resourcename.ToLower());" so the execution of my code will continue before the Resource is retrieved from the DB ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88903/discussion-between-john-koerner-and-john-g).